# Upload files via ftp with its sub directories using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have written a code that have to upload multiple files in azure web app using powershell.

I want to upload folder saved in $appdirectory variable.

```
$appdirectory="C:\scriptfolder\*"
$webappname="myapitestapp1"
$xml = [xml](Get-AzureRmWebAppPublishingProfile -Name $webappname -ResourceGroupName sibs -OutputFile null)
$xml = [xml]$xml
username = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userName").value
$password = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@userPWD").value
$url = $xml.SelectNodes("//publishProfile[@publishMethod=`"FTP`"]/@publishUrl").value

Set-Location $appdirectory
$webclient = New-Object -TypeName System.Net.WebClient
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $appdirectory -Recurse 

foreach ($file in $files)
{
    $relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri("$url/$relativepath")
    if($file.PSIsContainer)
    {
        #$uri.AbsolutePath + "is Directory"
        $ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($uri);
        $ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::MakeDirectory
        $ftprequest.UseBinary = $true

        $ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)

        $response = $ftprequest.GetResponse();
        $response.StatusDescription
        continue
    }
    "Uploading to " + $uri.AbsoluteUri
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $file.FullName)
} 
$webclient.Dispose()
```

its copying files that is from subfolder and uploading but it is not uploading the root directory. I want to upload all folder and files using powershell.

Comment: The Problem with my code is this that it add files of the directory in the root path.  and the root path files has . in it and also the files become hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace(".\", "").Replace('\', '/')
```

was wrong.

$relativepath = (Resolve-Path -Path $file.FullName -Relative).Replace('\', '/')

This worked and stopped hiding files